# MATLAB can't call Python module with imports

Tags: python, matlab

I've followed the instructions on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-defined-custom-module.html) page to have MATLAB call python code in a python module.

```
# mymod.py

def search(words):
    """Return list of words containing 'son'"""
    newlist = [w for w in words if 'son' in w]
    return newlist
```

Then in MATLAB I run

```
N = py.list({'Jones','Johnson','James'})
py.mymod.search(N)
```

and get the desired output. However, I can't get things to work when the python module itself has imports in it. For example, adding the single line `import numpy as np` to `mymod.py` yields the error

```
Undefined variable "py" or class "py.mymod.search"
```

upon running the same lines in MATLAB. How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure that MATLAB is calling the "right" Python version, for which NumPy is really installed? You can check the full path of the Python executable with `import sys; sys.executable`

Answer (score 2):

In the [matlab](https://www.slideshare.net/arifyunus90/matlab-module) book on page 110 you can see the list of possible reasons for why you saw this error and how to troubleshoot them.

**Reasons:**

1. "Python not installed" on page 1-70
2. "64-bit/32-bit Versions of Python on Windows Platforms" on page 1-70
3. "MATLAB Cannot Find Python" on page 1-71
4. "Error in User-Defined Python Module" on page 1-71
5. "Python Module Not on Python Search Path" on page 1-71
6. "Module Name Conflicts" on page 1-72
7. "Python Tries to Execute command in Wrong Module" on page 1-72

I would suggest working through this list of solutions as you can see there are several possible reasons for your error and it's hard for us to know which one it is without more information.

Comment: None of those issues resolve what's going on here. Note that the only difference between getting things to work and breaking them is the numpy import. The fact that things work without this is proof that the above possibilities aren't the problem